# Whatsapp calls are actually calling the phone number

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app, call

I have Verizon as Carrier.

With my iPhone, sometimes I want to call my mother in Italy, on her Whatsapp account.
So I open the Whatsapp app, go to the last chat thread with my mother and tap the top-right icon with the phone.

Sometimes, though, the call is performed using my U.S. Verizon number rather than my WhatsApp account and therefore Verizon has already charged me a few times for international calls!!

How can I make sure to perform the call using Whatsapp rather than the normal phone?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So turn off mobile data for WhatsApp in the phone settings.

That will force WhatsApp to only use Wifi for its connection.

I turned on mobile data as I was away from Wifi recently, but normally I only allow Wifi for WhatsApp.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot do that. I need to use Whatsapp also when I am not under Wifi coverage...

Comment: If I read the question correctly the problem isnt that WhatsApp is using mobile data, instead WhatsApp somehow falls back to a normal phone call instead of a WhatsApp call over data.

Comment: Exactly, x_841 is totally correct

Comment: @CristianoGhersi not seen that happen on my install and settings.